# Equivalency of bijection definitions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In my uni script, a bijective function is defined as a function that is simultaneously injective and surjective. However, while working through some set-theoretic proofs, I have also encountered a (to my understanding) different definition - that a function is bijective if domain and range have the same cardinality. Intuitively, it makes sense, but formally - why?

EDIT: For clarity, the definitions of injectivity and surjectivity I know from uni are of the form $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2$ and $\forall y\in Y \exists x\in X:y = f(x)$.

Comment: It's certainly not true if the cardinality is infinite.

Comment: This is false.  The inclusion function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ has domain and range of the same cardinality, but $f$ is not bijective.

Comment: @Randall so it is true for finite sets only I presume?

Comment: Still, no (if by range you mean image and not codomain).  The inclusion $\{1,2\} \to \{1,2,3\}$ has domain and range the same size, but is still not a bijection.

Comment: This is true for finite sets only. Formally, any map $f\colon X\to f(X)$ is a surjection, and if $|X|=|f(X)|$ is finite, than $f$ must be an injection. Otherwise some two elements of $X$ would map to the same element of $f(X)$ implying that $|X|>|f(X)|$.

Comment: @RandyMarsh but that is so only once you restrict $f$ in the codomain to be its range.  The "original" $f$ still need not have been bijective.

Comment: Perhaps what you encountered is not a definition, but a consequence.  **If** the function $f: X \to Y$ is bijective, **then** $X$ and $Y$ must have the same cardinality.  Thus if $X$ and $Y$ have different cardinalities, there is no bijection from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Indeed, @Randall. I am taking $f\colon X\to f(X)$ as the original, even though one would need to know $f$ in the first place before talking about $f(X)$. I was mostly writing it like that because "uni scripts" that I've seen like to conflate co-domain with range (I've seen many where co-domain isn't mentioned at all). The proper statement would be that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a surjection, and $|X|=|Y|<\infty$, then $f$ is a bijection.